# How to Get zoom effect in panorama viewer in three js

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js, zooming, panoramas

I just try to use the `three.js` to make a panorama slider, but I don't get the zooming effect.

I can't understand that how is possible. The viewSize that multiply to left, right, top and bottom to create a something near of a zoom effect.

This is my JavaScript code for viewer:

```
var camera, scene, renderer;
var geometry, material, mesh;
var target = new THREE.Vector3();
var lon = 90, lat = 0;
var phi = 0, theta = 0;
var touchX, touchY;

init();
animate();

function init() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var sides = [
        {
            url: '/demo2/posx.jpg',
            position: [-512, 0, 0],
            rotation: [0, Math.PI / 2, 0]
        },
        {
            url: '/demo2/negx.jpg',
            position: [512, 0, 0],
            rotation: [0, -Math.PI / 2, 0]
        },
        {
            url: '/demo2/posy.jpg',
            position: [0, 512, 0],
            rotation: [Math.PI / 2, 0, Math.PI]
        },
        {
            url: '/demo2/negy.jpg',
            position: [0, -512, 0],
            rotation: [-Math.PI / 2, 0, Math.PI]
        },
        {
            url: '/demo2/posz.jpg',
            position: [0, 0, 512],
            rotation: [0, Math.PI, 0]
        },
        {
            url: '/demo2/negz.jpg',
            position: [0, 0, -512],
            rotation: [0, 0, 0]
        }
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < sides.length; i++) {
        var side = sides[i];
        var element = document.createElement('img');
        element.width = 1026; // 2 pixels extra to close the gap.
        element.src = side.url;
        var object = new THREE.CSS3DObject(element);
        object.position.fromArray(side.position);
        object.rotation.fromArray(side.rotation);
        scene.add(object);
    }
    renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
    document.addEventListener('mousewheel', onDocumentMouseWheel, false);
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false);
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false);
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);
}

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
    var movementX = event.movementX || event.mozMovementX || event.webkitMovementX || 0;
    var movementY = event.movementY || event.mozMovementY || event.webkitMovementY || 0;
    lon -= movementX * 0.1;
    lat += movementY * 0.1;
}

function onDocumentMouseUp(event) {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp);
}

function onDocumentMouseWheel(event) {
    camera.fov -= event.wheelDeltaY * 0.05;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}

function onDocumentTouchStart(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var touch = event.touches[0];
    touchX = touch.screenX;
    touchY = touch.screenY;
}

function onDocumentTouchMove(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var touch = event.touches[0];
    lon -= ( touch.screenX - touchX ) * 0.1;
    lat += ( touch.screenY - touchY ) * 0.1;
    touchX = touch.screenX;
    touchY = touch.screenY;
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    lon += 0.1;
    lat = Math.max(-85, Math.min(85, lat));
    phi = THREE.Math.degToRad(90 - lat);
    theta = THREE.Math.degToRad(lon);
    target.x = Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta);
    target.y = Math.cos(phi);
    target.z = Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta);
    camera.lookAt(target);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Comment: "I think that is possible change..." so why not just try it?